# DataGridView data errors

Tags: datagridview

I have a datagridview with some customs columns and after commit changes in currentcelldirtystatechanged, dataerror event is raised so could it be the cause that I cannot exit edit mode from cells in datagridview. I am experimenting a weird behaviour when trying to exit cell's edit mode and I am not sure if the problem is that errors are raised in dataerror event. If so, how to solve data errors in datagridview?

Comment: Dataerror event is raised when you are not entering a valid value in a datagridview cell. This is most likely because you have set a custom input set for a cell (or its parent column) via its value type property. You will have tinker with that first. Decide for yourself if data validation should be done or not

Comment: ok, but if I decide in dataerror event to process it as e.cancel = false to discard the errors because they are not important for my case, could it affect when commit and validate cell's value through sentences like datagridview.endedit() or datagridview.commitedit()? I mean, despite not taking into account the errors by doing e.cancel = false, could I commit and validate without problems cell's value? and even discard changes using datagridview.canceledit()? I want to be sure that making e.cancel = false in dataerror event is not affecting and causing problems when committing and validating.

Comment: Yes you can do it. You can `e.cancel = false` and then have your own validation in endedit or commitedit. But the ideal way is to handle the case in dataerror event itself by checking the type of error. if you want to do all the validation yourself then why register the dataerror event at all?